# why get unexpected error?

Tags: java, php, android

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title']; 
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$channel = $_POST['channel'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("imammuda");
$sql=mysql_query("insert into Program (ID, Title, Date, Time, Channel) values ('NULL', $title, $date, $time, $channel);
mysql_close();
?>
```

this is my POST to insert data

```
private void adddataintophp(String title, String date, String time, String channel){
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //http post
    try{
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("channel", channel));
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/insertprogram.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

when run the php, it gave me

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\InsertProgram.php on line 10
```

i don't know why it cannot end.

please help me in the POST there too, i think got some errors there that i did not found it.

Comment: As you can see in the syntax highlighting, you are missing a quote. Make sure you use an IDE or editor with syntax highlighting

Comment: @Pekka - even SO's syntax highlighting shows it.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

close this sql query with `)"`

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into Program (ID, Title, Date, Time, Channel) values ('NULL', $title, $date, $time, $channel)");
```

Answer (score 6):

Close the double quote and put column values in single quotes

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into Program (ID, Title, Date, Time, Channel) 
                values ('NULL', '$title','$date', '$time', '$channel'");
```

A side note: Escape user inputs before sending them to mysql server.

Comment: what about this? Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\wamp\www\InsertProgram.php on line 2

Comment: @newbie:`$_POST['title']` does not exists. Check if the variable is set with `isset()` method before using them will erase this notice

Comment: `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));` i add this in the java post there, but i don't know how to define in php

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into Program (ID, Title, Date, Time, Channel) values ('NULL', $title, $date, $time, $channel)");
```

You forgot the end quote.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("insert into Program (ID, Title, Date, Time, Channel) values ('NULL', $title, $date, $time, $channel);
```

You didn't end the SQL-String. Add " on the end of the String.